# iPhone 5c does not alert imessages from email addresses

Tags: ios, messages

I have an iPhone 5c running iOS 9.3.1

Why does iMessage only give me sound and alerts when a message comes from a phone number and not when it comes from an email address?

Comment: How is the sender sending the non phone messages?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. could you edit this to correct my assumption on your version if needed? Also - are you aware of the do not disturb setting that can be enabled for a thread as opposed to the entire app/system?

Answer (score 1):

On the iPhone go to `Settings --> Notifications --> Messages` and make sure the following are all turned on, depending on what you want:

- `Allow Notifications`
- `Show in Notification Center`
- `Sounds --> <select sound>`
- `Badge App Icon`
- `Show on Lock Screen`

Under `Alert Style When Unlocked` select either `Banners` or `Alerts`, depending on how you want to be alerted.

As mentioned by @bmike, your `Do Not Disturb` setting will affect if the alerts go thru or not.